# Delete array value containing given text

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$array = array(
    [0] => "obm=SOME_TEXT",
    [1] => "sbm=SOME_TEXT",
    [2] => "obm=SOME_TEXT"
);
```

How can I remove array's element(s) containing value `obm` or `sbm` (which is always at the top of the string in the array) and update indexes?

Example 1:

```
print_r(arrRemove("smb", $array));
```

Output:

```
$array = array(
    [0] => "obm=SOME_TEXT",
    [1] => "obm=SOME_TEXT"
);
```

Example 2:

```
print_r(arrRemove("omb", $array));
```

Output:

```
$array = array(
    [0] => "sbm=SOME_TEXT"
);
```

Comment: I have no idea how could I do this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply loop through the array using a `foreach` and then use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) to check if the array contains the given input string, and [`array_values()`](http://php.net/array_values) to update the indexes:

```
function arrRemove($str, $input) {
    foreach ($input as $key => $value) {            
        // get the word before '='
        list($word, $text) = explode('=', $value); 

        // check if the word contains your searchterm
        if (strpos($word, $str) !== FALSE) {
            unset($input[$key]);
        }
    }
    return array_values($input);
}
```

Usage:

```
print_r(arrRemove('obm', $array));
print_r(arrRemove('sbm', $array));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => sbm=SOME_TEXT
)

Array
(
    [0] => obm=SOME_TEXT
    [1] => obm=SOME_TEXT
)
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/54318)

Comment: @GuillaumePoussel: Ah, yes. I didn't see that requirement in the question. I've updated the answer now. Thank you :-)

Comment: `sbm=plobma` will be filtered out. This is a false-positive I guess.

Comment: @GuillaumePoussel: The OP didn't state that as a requirement in the question. It says *How can I remove array's element(s) containing value "obm" or "sbm" (which is always at the top of the string in the array)*

Comment: @Amal Murali But it solvable by using as string "obm=" or "sbm="

Comment: @GuillaumePoussel: Updated the answer again. Anyway, I'm not convinced it deserves a downvote.

Comment: @user2758571: That's one way, but you can easily `explode()` the string to get the word before `=` sign. See the updated answer.

Comment: @AmalMurali It's ok, cause I need to explode the array later, I think I'll just use "obm=". Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
$newarray = array_values(array_filter($oldarray, function($value){
    return strpos($value, 'obm') !== 0;
}
));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is handled by PHP

[php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php)

array_pop() pops and returns the last value of the array , shortening the array by one element.